# Getting ParseError when parsing using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing, xml.etree

I am trying to extract the `<comment>` tag (using `xml.etree.ElementTree`) from the XML and find the `comment` count number and add all of the numbers. I am reading the file via a URL using **urllib** package.

sample data: http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml

But currently i am trying to trying to print the name, and count.

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

serviceurl = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml'

address = raw_input("Enter location: ") 
url = serviceurl + urllib.urlencode({'sensor': 'false', 'address': address})
print ("Retrieving: ", url)
link = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = link.read()
print("Retrieved ", len(data), "characters")


tree = ET.fromstring(data)

tags = tree.findall('.//comment')
for tag in tags:
    Name = ''
    count = '' 
    Name = tree.find('commentinfo').find('comments').find('comment').find('name').text
    count = tree.find('comments').find('comments').find('comment').find('count').number
    print Name, count
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to even parse the XML file into Python, because i am getting this error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ch13_parseXML_assignment.py", line 14, in <module>
    tree = ET.fromstring(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1300, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1642, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1506, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 49
```

I have read previously in a similar situation that maybe the parser isn't accepting the XML file. Anticipating this, i did a `Try` and `Except` around `tree = ET.fromstring(data)` and I was able to get past this line, but later it is throwing an erro saying `tree` variable is not defined. This defeats the purpose of the output I am expecting.

Can somebody please point me in a direction that helps me?

Comment: Have you looked at the actual downloaded content?

Comment: I can't really test this because I don't know what address to enter. But with a wild guess of 'foo', it worked. As suggested, print out what you got and look to see if its an error page.

Comment: It probably *shouldn't* work because the url is invalid. You likely want `url = serviceurl + "&" + urllib.urlencode({'sensor': 'false', 'address': address})`.